# Как получить id элементов расположенных в div?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Есть вот такой div

```
<tr><td <div ID="stroka" class="sortContainer"> 
<div id = "pol_3" class= "str"><\div>
<div id = "pol_1" class= "str"><\div>
<div id = "pol_2" class= "str"><\div>
</div></td></tr>
```

Как получить id внутренних div, в том порядке как они стоят?

Comment: @Ринат Давлетбаев, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 8):

С помощью jQuery легко выбрать все `div`'ы внутри данного:

```
jQuery( '#stroka > div');
```

Это выбирет все `<div>` внутри элемента с `id=stroka`. С угловой скобкой "`>`" выберутся только те `div`'ы, что лежат "в корне" `div#stroka`. Те что дальше внутри-внутри не выберутся. Если и они нужны - тогда без знака "больше":

```
jQuery( '#stroka div');
```

Затем нужно пробежаться по ним с помощью [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), а они идут в порядке, как в документе:

```
jQuery( '#stroka > div').each( function(index, element){ // ... } );
```

В `each()` надо положить функцию, которая получит на вход по очереди каждый из найденных элементов. Передается два параметра: `index` – `0,1,2 .. N` (порядковый номер очередного элемента, и `element` — сам элемент. В  нашем случае очередной внутренний `<div>`.

Теперь осталось из каждого получить значение атрибута "`id`". В jQuery для этого есть [метод `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). Напр., чтобы получить значение атрибута "id": `$( element).attr( "id")`. Итого, всё вместе:

```
$( "#stroka > div").each( function( index, element) {
    console.log( "id:", $( element).attr( "id"));
});
```

Пример с исправленным вашим html [на jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/Zk9kW/)

Answer (score 3):

у вас неправильно html сформированный, очень много ошибок. вот html вместе с javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/mj5R6/

Пользуйтесь специальными редакторами с подсветкой синтаксиса

Comment: Спасибо.Html я просто для примера составил.Он вообще у меня динамически создаётся.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getIdInDiv(id) {
    var stroka = Array.from(document.getElementById(id).children);
    var array = []; // Массив из id
    for (let i = 0; i < stroka.length; i++) {
        array.push(stroka[i].getAttribute('id'));
    }
    return array;
}

alert(getIdInDiv('stroka'));
```

```html
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="stroka" class="sortContainer"> 
      <div id = "pol_3" class= "str"></div>
      <div id = "pol_1" class= "str"></div>
      <div id = "pol_2" class= "str"></div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

И без JQuery